# how to prepend multiple &nbsp using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day,

How to add multiple spaces before the text on javascript? Here's what Im doing but it only add "&nbsp" word before the word instead of blank spaces.

my HTML

```
 <table class="report-table">
 <tbody>
             <tr class="indent-0 highLight bold">
                 <td>Asset</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="indent-1 bold ">
                 <td >Current Assets</td>
                 <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>

             </tr>
             <tr  class="indent-2">
                <td>Bank Accounts</td>
                <td class="emptyRow"></td>
                <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>
                 <td class="rowValue">9,999,999.00</td>


             </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

my JS

```
$('.report-table tr ').each(function(){
        var classList = [];
        classList = this.className.split(' ');
        var space = '';
        console.log(classList);

        for(var x = 0; classList.length > x ; x++)
        {
            if(hasNumbers(classList[x]))
            {
            var value = classList[x].replace( /^\D+/g, ''); 
            var string = getString(classList[x]);

                if(string == 'indent')
                {
                    for(z=0; z<=value; z++)
                    {
                        space += '&nbsp';
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        $(this).find('td:first-child').prepend(space);
 });
```

result:  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspWordHere!

Thanks for the help and have a good day ahead!

Comment: Your code works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/tLm32kue/)

Comment: hmm..I should edit that into actual codes i used. :) sorry for that.. I thought it would be the same if Ill put it on simple code.

Comment: The result you posted omitted the `';'` characters. Did you have a typo in your original code?

Comment: ohh **** its the ';' ive been missing all this time! how reckless of me.. should i delete my post instead.? Thank your very much for that! I tried "\t", " ", and finally &nbsp but it sadly didnt worked for me. xD anyways sorry for the inconvenience !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me. From the result, you're missing the semi-colon ';' in your real script?

http://jsfiddle.net/0kr6sc9j/

```
var space = "";
for(var z=0;z<=5;z++){
    space += '&nbsp;';
}
$("p").prepend(space);
```